# MySQL, using less than or equal to locks the whole table?

Tags: mysql, transactions

When I use `c1<=4` or even `c1<4 OR c1=4` Transaction A locks the whole table.
But if I use only one of them, it does not happen. Why is that? What happened to the "next-key lock"?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(c1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(c1));
INSERT INTO t1 (c1) VALUES (1),(5),(10);

# Transaction A and B starts at the same time

#teste 1
A does, SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1<=4 FOR UPDATE;
B does, SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1=10 FOR UPDATE; # blocked!

#teste 2
A does, SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1<4 FOR UPDATE;
B does, SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1=10 FOR UPDATE; # worked!

#teste 3
A does, SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1=4 FOR UPDATE;
B does, SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1=10 FOR UPDATE; # worked!
```

Comment: You should run `EXPLAIN` on all these queries.

Comment: Your example is not repeatable.

Comment: if you mean isolation level, yes it is repeatable read